# Expected Unique Toys

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, coupon-collector-problem

Suppose there are n types of toys, which you are collecting one by one. Each time you collect a toy, it is equally likely to be any of the n types. What is the expected number of distinct toy types that you have after you have collected t toys? (Assume that you will definitely collect t toys, whether or not you obtain a complete set before then.)

I thought of doing like this : X = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + .... + X_t where , X_i is indicator of whether i_th toy is unique or not

E(X) can be found by linearity . But to get that , we need to get E(X_i) which is quite hard for me to interpret.

I feel that my approach is not to fit to solve this problem. Pls tell possible flaws and the right thought process.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was nearly right but I would think about the expectation of having collected the $j$th toy after each draw, and then summing the expectation over the toys.

The expected number of unique toys $X_t$ is the sum of the expectations of $Y_{tj}$ of having collected the $j$th toy at least once in the first $t$ draws.

Each toy is equally likely to be drawn, so the chance that it is collected at least once in the first $t$ draws is $1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^t$.  This is the expectation of having collected (say) toy 1 after $t$ draws.

Summing this over each possible toy gives you

$E(X_t) = n\times\left(1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^t\right)$

**Edit:** I should have checked the related questions there is a lengthier explanation of the same problem here [The expected number of unique elements drawn with replacement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296005/the-expected-number-of-unique-elements-drawn-with-replacement?rq=1)